# How to call C# function from UnityScript

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to call C# function from a UnityScript `GameMaster.js` like this.

#### GameMaster.js

```
#pragma strict

function Start () {
  print(Mahjong.Foo());
}
```

#### Mahjong.cs

```
using System.Collections;

public class Mahjong {
  string Foo () {
    return "foo";
  }
}
```

When I run the program, I get `BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'Mahjong'.`.
According to information from [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/4042-Importing-Javascript-Classes), if script files are in Assets directory, I don't need to `import` file.

But it doesn't works in my case. what am I missing?
How can I call #C's function from UnityScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# script has to be compiled before the JS script for this to work. To achieve this you have to move the C# script into one of the following directories: Plugins, Standard Assets or Pro Standard Assets.

It also works the other way around - if you want to call JS from C#, move the JS into one of the folders.

It does not work both ways at once however.

Comment: You can also use SendMessage to invoke a C# method from Javascript (or vice-versa), but your are limited to passing one parameter, and you can't get the return value. So pretty limited, but sometimes useful.